# What's the best way to manage (Created/Updated/Deleted)-by for a Model

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5.1, activitylog

I'm using Laravel 5.1, what's the best way to manage activity-log of a given table on : `Create_by`, `Updated_by`, `Deleted_by` (like `created_at`, `updated_at` and `deleted_at`) ?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I've got the solution 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events